# Why can't I execute a client-side hook script when committing a switched path?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoise-svn

I have got an SVN repository (version 1.9.2), and I am using a TortoiseSVN client (version 1.9.2) on a Windows 7 (x64) machine. There are client-side hook scripts (start-commit, pre-commit and post-commit), which are stored within the repository and of course available in the local working copy. They scripts are installed by using the special properties `tsvn:startcommithook`, `tsvn:precommithook` and `tsvn:postcommithook`, each pointing to the respective script file using the `%REPOROOT%` variable to avoid having to specify the absolute working copy path.

When I commit changes to the repository, the hook scripts (batch files, `.bat`) all work fine.

However, when I try to commit changes to files in a switched path, the following error appears:
[image]
And the commit cannot be done after confirming the message, the commit dialog does not appear.

I believe this error is not triggered by the hook scripts (because there is no change when I write `exit 0` or `exit 1` into the scripts as the only command), but by TortoiseSVN when trying to execute them, which, for some reason, seems not to be able to find the respective script any more.

So how can I use hook scripts that are located in the repository and hence in the working copy?

---

Replacing the variable `%REPOROOT%` by full absolute paths does not change the behaviour at all.

When I replace variable `%REPOROOT%` by `%REPOROOT+%` in the `tsvn:*commithook` properties, nothing changes for switched paths (so the aforementioned error message appears), but for standard paths, no hook script is executed and there is no error message after all.

---

Just as a side note: to verify whether or not a hook script is attempted to be fired, I rely on appearance of the approval/reject dialog of TortoiseSVN:
[image: Approve or reject client-side hook script]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? Have the exact same issue right now.

Comment: Not yet unfortunately, @Carson. It appears to be a bug of TortoiseSVN to me. Perhaps somebody else knows. Thanks for the bounty, by the way!

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, a switched path is a path in the working directory that is relinked to another repository directory (by [Tortoise]SVN's Switch feature) than the repository tree reflected; e. g., there is a repository tree `project/branches/sub/a`, `project/branches/sub/b`, `project/branches/sub/c`, `project/trunk/sub` and the latter checked out to working copy `C:\SVN\project\sub`; you can now switch `C:\SVN\project\sub` to `project/branches/a/sub`; do Check for Modifications, there is the number of Switched items displayed in the bottom right; those paths I am talking about...

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, the issue cannot be caused by the hook batch script, because it appears even when I just place a single command `exit 0` in it. `%REPOROOT%` should resolve to the URL of the root of the repository (not the working copy), according to TortoiseSVN's help; the hook scripts are placed in `^/hooks/`, so the path is `%REPOROOT%/hooks/script.bat`...

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to someway `echo` that `%REPOROOT%` to a log file or something to confirm what exactly it is resolving path wise and then you could check that path to verify it is accurate. I'll read over the TortoiseSVN document with more detail later when I get more time, seems to be an issue with it not finding a file it is referencing so anything you can think of or try to validate such variables, etc. would be a good starting point at least I would think.

Comment: Yes, I agree, @PimpJuiceIT, `%REPOROOT%` needs to be checked. I have no idea how though, because the script does not run, so `echo` is useless there... (When I commit the parent directory of a switched path, everything works es expected...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Work-Around

To work around the issue, just commit the parent directory of the switch path rather than the switched path itself or a child item of it.

Just to have mentioned it: it does *not* change behaviour to apply the hook script property recursively.

---

#### Syntax for Hook Script Path (properties `tsvn:*hook`)

First of all, when specifying the path to a hook script, it is very important that as soon as you use one of the placeholders `%REPOROOT%` or `%REPOROOT+%`, you must use the forward-slash `/` as the path separator. I believe this is linked to the fact that these variables contain the URL to the repository root internally, according to the [documentation](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-tsvn-props), but not a local working copy (WC) path. For fixed local paths, both forward-slashes `/` and backslashes `\` are accepted.
In case the path contains <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, you must put it in between quotation marks; you might use quotation in general as it does not harm anyway.

---

#### Normal vs. Switched Path, Directory Levels

Let us assume we have a repository at `D:\TEST\repo` containing `/trunk`, `/branches`, `/tags` and `/hooks` at top-level, a script `script.bat` in `/hooks` with the content `exit 0`, a file called `file.txt` in `/trunk`, a branch of `/trunk` at `/branches/test` and another branch of `/trunk` at `/branch`; the WC is checked out at `D:\TEST\wc`, but we have a [sparse checkout](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html#tsvn-dug-checkout-depth) so that only `/trunk` and `/hooks` are there (both fully recursively).

Then set up a new property `tsvn:startcommithook` at the WC root, like this:
[image: Hook Script Property Setup Dialog]

Now try to commit anything at any WC location (root, `/trunk`, etc.); the hook script approve/reject dialog appears, showing the following hook script path, which is the correct one, so the script actually runs upon clicking 'Run':
[image: Hook Script Execution Approval/Rejection Dialog]

Now switch the local WC path `D:\TEST\wc\trunk` to `/branches/test`, then try to commit the local WC file `file.txt`; the approve/reject dialog shows the following wrong path this time:
[image: Hook Script Execution Approval/Rejection Dialog]

When clicking 'Run', the script cannot be executed, obviously:
[image: Hook Script Execution Failure]

But when switching the local WC path `D:\TEST\wc\trunk` to `/branch` now and trying to commit the local WC file `file.txt`, the approve/reject dialog shows the correct path again like [above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOvSU.png), and the script is able to run.

So apparently, different depths in the directory hierarchy level of normal and switched paths seem to derogate proper expansion of the placeholder `%REPOROOT%`.
This behaviour is exactly the same in case the hook script has been committed or not.

#### Confirmed Bug

I reported the aforementioned behaviour [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tortoisesvn/LEv1NhuUQqE/I0oSLJNpDgAJ), it has been confirmed to be a bug [there](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tortoisesvn/LEv1NhuUQqE/GMv56NgZDQAJ), which has meanwhile been fixed in [r28670](https://osdn.net/projects/tortoisesvn/scm/svn/commits/28670#fd-trunk/src/Utils/Hooks.cpp) and will therefore no longer be present in versions beyond 1.12.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I switched to %REPOROOT+% to make it work after branching (coping).

As for the script, I was running a batch file and added this line to make it run from the batch file location and not the triggering folder:

cd /d %~dp0

Comment: I'm having a different problem now. i've set this folder as an external on another folder and the hook doesn't execute, any idea how to trigger the hook?

Comment: Well, do you mean the folder containing the hook script is an external? Anyway, I didn't do any experiments with externals, so I guess I can't tell. However, you could ask a new question about that, precisely describing your repository and working copy setups...